# ¿Obtener metodos, atributos de otras clases y proyectos en JAVA?

Tags: java

Necesito que desde un codigo en JAva obtener los atributos de otra clase, no estoy hablando de programacion orientada a objetos, mas bien seria algo asi.

Mi programa recibe como entrada una direccion donde esta ubicado otro archivo JAVA(De otro proyecto)
Y como salida obtener
    Nombre de la clase
    Saber si es una interface o clase abstracta
    Interfaces que implementa
    Clases  de la que hereda
    Cada uno de sus metodos y atributos, especificando que tipo de valor regresa y su accesibilidad

¿Alguna herramienta para hacer esto o alguna idea?

Mi idea simplemente es acceder al archivo java como un archivo de texto y con las condiciones evaluar linea por linea, pero en lo personal siento que se presta mucho a errores, por eso me gustaría una herramienta que haga algo parecido.

Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Bueno no se para que es requerido el tema, pero si la clase java esta dentro del classpath del proyecto se puede usar el api reflection de java. En el siguiente ejemplo se tiene una clase con el nombre `ClaseJava.java` y al método `obtenerMapAtributoValor` se le pasa un objeto de tipo `ClaseJava`

```
public class ObjectUtil {

    public Map<String, String> obtenerMapAtributoValor(ClaseJava claseJava){
        Map<String, String> mapAtributoValor = new HashMap<>();

        Class<?> clase = claseJava.getClass();
        Field[] atributos = clase.getDeclaredFields();

        try {
            for(Field field : atributos) {
                field.setAccessible(true);
                String name = field.getName();
                String value = (String)field.get(claseJava);
                mapAtributoValor.put(name, value);
            }
        }catch(IllegalAccessException iae) {
            iae.printStackTrace();
        }catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return mapAtributoValor;
}
```