# Multiples valores en un metodo java

Tags: java

Muy buenas.
Resulta que tengo que crear un método en java que muestre todas las propiedades de mi clase mediante **Strings**, y por mas vueltas que le doy no consigo sacarlo.
Estaría muy agradecido si algún rey Midas pudiese sacarme de este callejón. Gracias de antemano.

```
public String[] toString() 
{
      String[] mostrar = new String[] 
      {
          nombre, 
          dni, 
          String.valueOf(edad), 
          String.valueOf(sexo), 
          String.valueOf(peso),   
          String.valueOf(altura)
       };

    return mostrar[];               
}
```

Comment: Dejo esta enlace a una pregunta similar, espero le sea de ayuda. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/303765/obtener-metodos-atributos-de-otras-clases-y-proyectos-en-java/303788#303788

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solo necesitas concatenar los atributos;

```
package com;

public class Myclase {
    private String nombre;
    private String dni;
    private int edad;
    private char sexo;
    private double peso;
    private double altura;
    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }
    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }
    public String getDni() {
        return dni;
    }
    public void setDni(String dni) {
        this.dni = dni;
    }
    public int getEdad() {
        return edad;
    }
    public void setEdad(int edad) {
        this.edad = edad;
    }
    public char getSexo() {
        return sexo;
    }
    public void setSexo(char sexo) {
        this.sexo = sexo;
    }
    public double getPeso() {
        return peso;
    }
    public void setPeso(double peso) {
        this.peso = peso;
    }
    public double getAltura() {
        return altura;
    }
    public void setAltura(double altura) {
        this.altura = altura;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Myclase [nombre=" + nombre + ", dni=" + dni + ", edad=" + edad + ", sexo=" + sexo + ", peso=" + peso
                + ", altura=" + altura + "]";
    }
}
```